# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. Kivy package problem?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm getting the follow TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. Having read about this error I understand that the error is due to trying to access a None value but the below error isn't actually something in my code, it looks like it's coming from the kivy package? Any hints on what might be wrong?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/callu/OneDrive/Documents/Voting app/main.py", line 81, in <module>
     kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")
   File "C:\Users\callu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 301, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\callu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 368, in load_string
     parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
   File "C:\Users\callu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 401, in __init__
     self.parse(content)
   File "C:\Users\callu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 510, in parse
     objects, remaining_lines = self.parse_level(0, lines)
   File "C:\Users\callu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 614, in parse_level
     level + 1, lines[i:], spaces)
   File "C:\Users\callu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 614, in parse_level
     level + 1, lines[i:], spaces)
   File "C:\Users\callu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 673, in parse_level
     if current_property[:3] == 'on_':
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE votes (email NOT NULL, password NOT NULL, votes_yes INTEGER, votes_no INTEGER)""")


class LoginWindow(Screen):
    email = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)

    def login(self):
        with conn:
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM votes WHERE email = ? And password = ?, (self.email.text, self.password.text)")
            result = cur.fetchone()
            if result:
                self.reset()
                sm.current = "voting"
            else:
                invalid_login()

    def reset(self):
        self.email.text = ""
        self.password.text = ""


class VotingWindow(Screen):
    email = ObjectProperty()

    def yes_btn(self):
        with conn:
            cur.execute("UPDATE votes set vote_yes = 1 WHERE email = self.email.text")

    def no_btn(self):
        with conn:
            cur.execute("UPDATE votes set vote_no = 1 WHERE email = self.email.text")


class CreateAccountWindow(Screen):
    email = ObjectProperty()
    password = ObjectProperty()

    def create_btn(self):
        with conn:
            results = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM votes WHERE email = ?, (self.email.text,)")
            if results:
                invalid_form()
            else:
                cur.execute("INSERT into votes VALUES(email = ?, password = ?), (self.email.text, self.password.text)")
                self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.email.text = ""
        self.password.text = ""


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


def invalid_login():
    pop = Popup(title='Invalid Login',
                  content=Label(text='Invalid username or password.'),
                  size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
    pop.open()

def invalid_form():
    pop = Popup(title='Error',
                  content=Label(text='An account already exists with that email address'),
                  size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
    pop.open()


kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")
sm = WindowManager()

screens = [LoginWindow(name="login"), CreateAccountWindow(name="create account"), VotingWindow(name="voting")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = "login"


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()

conn.close()
```

```
WindowManager:
    LoginWindow:
    VotingWindow:
    CreateAccountWindow:

<LoginWindow>:
    name: "login"

    email: email
    password: password

    FloatLayout:

        FloatLayout:

            Label:
                text: "Email: "
                size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.2, "top": 0.9}


            TextInput:
                id: email
                multiline: False
                size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.4, "top": 0.9}

            Label:
                text: "Password: "
                size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.2, "top": 0.8}

            TextInput:
                id: password
                multiline: False
                size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.4, "top": 0.8}

        Button:
            text: "Login"
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.3, "top": 0.4}
            on_release: root.login()

        Button:
            text: "Don't have an account? Create one!"
            size_hint: 0.35, 0.05
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.325, "top": 0.1}
            on_release:\
                app.root.current = "create account"
                root.create_btn()


<VotingWindow>:
    name: "voting"

    FloatLayout:

        Button:
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "top": 0.9}
            text: "Insert story about company here"
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.4

        Button:
            text: "Yes"
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "top": 0.4}
            on_press: root.yes_btn()

        Button:
            text: "No"
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.6, "top": 0.4}
            on_press: root.no_btn()

        Button:
            text: "Logout"
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "top": 0.15}
            on_release: app.root.current = "login"

<CreateAccountWindow>:
    name: "create account"

    email: email
    password: password

    FloatLayout:

        FloatLayout:

            Label:
                text: "Create an account"
                size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.3, "top": 0.9}

            Label:
                text: "Email: "
                size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.2, "top": 0.7}


            TextInput:
                id: email
                multiline: False
                size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.4, "top": 0.7}

            Label:
                text: "Password: "
                size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.2, "top": 0.6}

            TextInput:
                id: password
                multiline: False
                size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.4, "top": 0.6}

        Button:
            text: "Create Account"
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.3, "top": 0.3}
            on_release: \
                app.root.current = "login"
                root.create_btn()
```

Comment: Please post a minimal runnable example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Apologies, I've now added the code in

Comment: Please reduce the size of the example, it's unlikely that all this code is necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I've tried deleting all the classes one by one in both the kv file and the python file but the error remains the same. The only time something changes is when I delete the kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv") section. When I do this the window opens as if it's going to launch the app and then immediately closes with the same error message

Comment: You say that like it's a bad thing, but it sounds great! It's much easier to debug if the effect of your own code can be discounted. Delete as much as you can and then post the new code and the full traceback again.

Comment: Ah thanks for the guidance! It was a rogue backslash in my kv file. on_release:\
                app.root.current = "create account"
                root.create_btn()

Comment: The other reason for requesting a minimal runnable example is that users often discover what the problem is while creating one - narrowing down the search space is an essential part of debugging!